# CSS table-cell floted contents affecting alignment of another table-cell contents

Tags: css, css-float

When I take some floating contents in a `table-cell` element, it affects alignment of contents of next 'table-cell'. Even if I remove the floating affect.

Please have a look [here](http://cssdesk.com/ttEZ7).

Now if I make last cell contents floated then contents in all cell shifted downs;

Please tell me the reason behind this not the fix.

Answer (score 0):

### To Fix:

Now that it's like a `table-cell`, you'd add:

```
<div class="cell aligntop">
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .aligntop { 
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
```

to the middle element, forcing the content to sit along the top - **Demo**: http://cssdesk.com/2sY46

[image: Align Along the top]

### Why was this happening?

> The [default behaviour/vertical-align](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) for a `table-cell` is: **`baseline`** thus, the content is natrually being pushed to the bottom. Although when you apply a class, `.left` which is asking the content to be pushed in certain manner, `float: left;` kicks in and adjoins it to the upper left of the table-cell after being floated - also see [vertical-align MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) for more information.

Comment: This is a fix. I am looking for reason.

Comment: @articlestack Updated, I hope it gives you an understanding with the default table-cell behaviour!

Comment: I have simplified the actual which shows that contents in a cell comes in top-left by default.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in: http://cssdesk.com/KLBzv

Two things:

1. float:left without an float right between the divs and the clear, or i dont know what you want;
2. all cells have the css vertical-align:top and the number the middle in this property